# Performance problems during GPU-intensive tasks (NVIDIA)

Tags: drivers, xorg, nvidia, gpu, proprietary-drivers

I have strange performance problems while rendering on GPU in Blender. For example, my cursor (together with the entire UI) lags occasionally and when trying to make a screenshot with ksnip the cursor is extremely hard to move since it lags a lot. This appears to only happen when rendering.

I have been a Debian (also with Plasma) user for a couple of years and recently decided to try Manjaro (installed via Architect because I haven’t found a way to partition the disk how I want in the graphical installer). I had no similar problems on Debian 10 with the 460.56 driver version.

A little demonstration of what I am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9iya.jpg

upd: I have noticed that Xorg CPU usage grows up to ~10% when this stuttering occurs.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.10.42-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.1.0 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.10-x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg0-rootvol rw 
  cryptdevice=UUID=6afec7bc-41b1-40f2-8198-a4fea301c902:cryptroot 
  udev.log_priority=3 pci=nomsi 
  Console: tty pts/2 wm: kwin_x11 DM: SDDM Distro: Manjaro Linux 
  base: Arch Linux 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: OMEN by HP Laptop v: Type1ProductConfigId 
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: N/A 
  Mobo: HP model: 825F v: 82.73 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: F.49 
  date: 07/19/2018 
Memory:
  RAM: total: 31.32 GiB used: 11.5 GiB (36.7%) 
  Array-1: capacity: 32 GiB slots: 2 EC: None max-module-size: 16 GiB 
  note: est. 
  Device-1: Bottom-Slot 1(left) size: 16 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: DDR4 
  detail: synchronous bus-width: 64 bits total: 64 bits manufacturer: Kingston 
  part-no: KHX2400C14S4/16G serial: <filter> 
  Device-2: Bottom-Slot 2(right) size: 16 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: DDR4 
  detail: synchronous bus-width: 64 bits total: 64 bits manufacturer: Kingston 
  part-no: KHX2400C14S4/16G serial: <filter> 
CPU:
  Info: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-6700HQ socket: U3E1 bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP arch: Skylake-S family: 6 model-id: 5E (94) stepping: 3 
  microcode: E2 cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 6 MiB L3: 6 MiB bogomips: 41621 
  Speed: 3122 MHz min/max: 800/3500 MHz base/boost: 2000/8300 volts: 0.8 V 
  ext-clock: 100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3122 2: 3189 3: 3236 4: 3144 
  5: 3157 6: 3263 7: 3259 8: 3142 
  Flags: 3dnowprefetch abm acpi adx aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon art 
  avx avx2 bmi1 bmi2 bts clflush clflushopt cmov constant_tsc cpuid 
  cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts epb ept ept_ad erms est 
  f16c flexpriority flush_l1d fma fpu fsgsbase fxsr hle ht hwp hwp_act_window 
  hwp_epp hwp_notify ibpb ibrs ida intel_pt invpcid invpcid_single lahf_lm lm 
  mca mce md_clear mmx monitor movbe mpx msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat 
  pbe pcid pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36 pti pts 
  rdrand rdseed rdtscp rep_good rtm sdbg sep smap smep ss ssbd sse sse2 sse4_1 
  sse4_2 ssse3 stibp syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_adjust 
  tsc_deadline_timer vme vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xgetbv1 xsave xsavec xsaveopt 
  xsaves xtopology xtpr 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled 
  Type: l1tf 
  mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable 
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
  Type: spec_store_bypass 
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, 
  IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
  Type: tsx_async_abort mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106BM [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6GB] 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nvidia v: 465.31 
  alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1c60 
  class-ID: 0300 
  Device-2: Microdia Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
  bus-ID: 1-2.3:5 chip-ID: 0c45:6340 class-ID: 0102 
  Device-3: Sunplus Innovation HP Wide Vision HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  bus-ID: 1-4:6 chip-ID: 1bcf:2c87 class-ID: 0e02 
  Display: server: X.org 1.20.11 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: loaded: nvidia 
  resolution: <missing: xdpyinfo> 
  Message: Unable to show advanced data. Required tool glxinfo missing. 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 
  chip-ID: 8086:a170 class-ID: 0403 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:10f1 
  class-ID: 0403 
  Device-3: Microdia Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
  bus-ID: 1-2.3:5 chip-ID: 0c45:6340 class-ID: 0102 
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.10.42-1-MANJARO running: yes 
  Sound Server-2: JACK v: 0.125.0 running: no 
  Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 14.2 running: yes 
  Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.30 running: yes 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 4000 
  bus-ID: 08:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:095a class-ID: 0280 
  IF: wlo1 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus-ID: 09:00.0 
  chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200 
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  IP v4: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global 
  broadcast: <filter> 
  WAN IP: <filter> 
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 
  bus-ID: 1-7:7 chip-ID: 8087:0a2a class-ID: e001 
  Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 1 state: down bt-service: disabled 
  rfk-block: hardware: no software: no address: see --recommends 
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default) 
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 19.98 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 
  dev: /dev/dm-2 maj-min: 254:2 mapped: vg0-swapvol label: N/A 
  uuid: d5cfb69c-e8ea-4155-bdf6-b4266cce62a3 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 78.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 62 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 393 Uptime: 6h 40m wakeups: 7 Init: systemd v: 248 
  tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 11.1.0 clang: 12.0.0 Packages: 1574 
  pacman: 1568 lib: 458 flatpak: 6 Shell: Zsh (sudo) v: 5.8 default: Bash 
  v: 5.1.8 running-in: yakuake inxi: 3.3.04
```

Xorg:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AOC 27G2G4"
    HorizSync       160.0 - 160.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 144.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DP-1: 1920x1080_144 +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "DPI" "96 x 96"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-1: 1920x1080_144 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I've got the same issue with CUDA workflows. Even some https://www.shadertoy.com shader toys lead to this issue.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov just found about it too. Tried a heavy shader on glslsandbox and experienced the same UI lag that I never had on Debian.

Comment: I’ve checked Xorg’s log and found something interesting:

`[   743.117] (II) event4  - Logitech G403 Prodigy Gaming Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[   743.638] (II) event4  - Logitech G403 Prodigy Gaming Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[   743.892] (II) event4  - Logitech G403 Prodigy Gaming Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
...
[   744.666] (II) event4  - Logitech G403 Prodigy Gaming Mouse: WARNING: log rate limit exceeded (5 msgs per 30s). Discarding future messages.`

Comment: Xorg is largely single threaded, so this is expected.

Comment: I didn't have this behavior on Debian. What could be the cause?

Comment: I've always had it for as long as I can remember, so I'm not sure why Debian was exempt for you. Probably something about their kernel configuration which hid the issue.